# How can I programmatically create an array of tuples?

Tags: rust

I figure there must be a dynamic way to do the following. There is an implied question here which is how can you dynamically create arrays of primitive values? Please note: I do not want a Vector.

```
let mut positional_frequencies: [[(u16, char); 26]; 5] = [ 
             [(0, 'A'), (0, 'B'), (0, 'C'), (0, 'D'), (0, 'E'),
             (0, 'F'), (0, 'G'), (0, 'H'), (0, 'I'), (0, 'J'),
             (0, 'K'), (0, 'L'), (0, 'M'), (0, 'N'), (0, 'O'),
             (0, 'P'), (0, 'Q'), (0, 'R'), (0, 'S'), (0, 'T'),
             (0, 'U'), (0, 'V'), (0, 'W'), (0, 'X'), (0, 'Y'),
             (0, 'Z')],
             [(0, 'A'), (0, 'B'), (0, 'C'), (0, 'D'), (0, 'E'),
             (0, 'F'), (0, 'G'), (0, 'H'), (0, 'I'), (0, 'J'),
             (0, 'K'), (0, 'L'), (0, 'M'), (0, 'N'), (0, 'O'),
             (0, 'P'), (0, 'Q'), (0, 'R'), (0, 'S'), (0, 'T'),
             (0, 'U'), (0, 'V'), (0, 'W'), (0, 'X'), (0, 'Y'),
             (0, 'Z')],
             [(0, 'A'), (0, 'B'), (0, 'C'), (0, 'D'), (0, 'E'),
             (0, 'F'), (0, 'G'), (0, 'H'), (0, 'I'), (0, 'J'),
             (0, 'K'), (0, 'L'), (0, 'M'), (0, 'N'), (0, 'O'),
             (0, 'P'), (0, 'Q'), (0, 'R'), (0, 'S'), (0, 'T'),
             (0, 'U'), (0, 'V'), (0, 'W'), (0, 'X'), (0, 'Y'),
             (0, 'Z')],
             [(0, 'A'), (0, 'B'), (0, 'C'), (0, 'D'), (0, 'E'),
             (0, 'F'), (0, 'G'), (0, 'H'), (0, 'I'), (0, 'J'),
             (0, 'K'), (0, 'L'), (0, 'M'), (0, 'N'), (0, 'O'),
             (0, 'P'), (0, 'Q'), (0, 'R'), (0, 'S'), (0, 'T'),
             (0, 'U'), (0, 'V'), (0, 'W'), (0, 'X'), (0, 'Y'),
             (0, 'Z')],
             [(0, 'A'), (0, 'B'), (0, 'C'), (0, 'D'), (0, 'E'),
             (0, 'F'), (0, 'G'), (0, 'H'), (0, 'I'), (0, 'J'),
             (0, 'K'), (0, 'L'), (0, 'M'), (0, 'N'), (0, 'O'),
             (0, 'P'), (0, 'Q'), (0, 'R'), (0, 'S'), (0, 'T'),
             (0, 'U'), (0, 'V'), (0, 'W'), (0, 'X'), (0, 'Y'),
             (0, 'Z')]
         ];
```

Comment: Are zeroes supposed to be repeated throughout? Or should it go 0,1,2,3,4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more idiomatic and performant way is to use iterators:

```rust
    let mut positional_frequencies: [[(u16, char); 26]; 5] = Default::default();
    for outer in positional_frequencies.iter_mut() {
        for (inner, c) in outer.iter_mut().zip('A'..='Z') {
            *inner = (0, c);
        }
    }
```

By using iterators, you don't have to worry about accidentally messing up the bounds. For instance, if you change the array to a length of six, you'll automatically be covered here.

`zip` combines two iterators, creating a pair for each element. This way, you don't need any direct character addition or `as` casts.

Comment: And because I just discovered it today, using `itertools`: `outer.iter_mut().set_from(std::iter::zip(std::iter::repeat(0), 'A'..));`.

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically create that exact output, you can initialize your array to a default value, then assign a tuple to the location in the array via a nested `for` loop iterating over the indices:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut positional_frequencies: [[(u16, char); 26]; 5] = Default::default();
    for i in 0..5 {
        for j in 0..26 {
            positional_frequencies[i][j] = (0, (b'A' + j as u8) as char);
        }
    } 
    println!("{:#?}", positional_frequencies);
}
```